# Using C# to make decisions based on lines in text files

Tags: c#, batch-file

I need to write a C# console application that can be called by a scheduled task. What I need to do is compare two
text files of dates. One file will have more dates than the other. The application will need to compare a list of dates to the current date, and run a batch file based on the date.

If there's a date in file A that's equal to today's date, then look at file B to see if today's date is contained in file B.
If it is in file B, run batch file "B". If today's date is not listed in file B, but is in file A, run batch file "A". If today's date is not listed in either text file, do nothing.

As an example:
File A has dates of, 
1/1/2015
1/8/2015
1/15/2015
1/22/2015
1/29/2015

File B has dates of,
1/15/2015
2/15/2015
3/15/2015

Let's assume today is 1/15/2015. The application checks file A and sees that today's date exists. It then goes on to check 
file B and finds that todays date exits so it runs the batch file "B". If today's date was not in file B, it would run batch file "A".

If today was 1/31/2015, neither would be true, and no batch files would run.

This is what I have so far. Fyi... I'm new to C# and new to programming in general. Thanks in advance for any assistance.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;

namespace Automate_Script
{
    class Program
    {
        // get today's date
        private static DateTime today = DateTime.Today;

        // create the string arrays to hold the dates from the text files.     Initialize to null.
        private static string[] dateLinesWeek = null;
        private static string[] dateLinesMonth = null;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // display today's date in console window.
            Console.WriteLine("\n\t\tToday is {0}", today.ToString("d"));

            // attempts to read the 'weekDates' text file.
            try
            {
                // this is the text file that contains the dates for week-end run dates.
                dateLinesWeek = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\MyScripts\weekDates.txt");
                dateLinesMonth = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\MyScripts\monthDates.txt");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }

            // create the process to run the batch execution.
            Process p = new Process();

            // iterate through the 'weekDates' text file
            foreach (var weekLine in dateLinesWeek)
            {
                if (Convert.ToDateTime(weekLine) == today)
                {
                    foreach (var monthLine in dateLinesMonth)
                    {
                        if (Convert.ToDateTime(monthLine) == today && Convert.ToDateTime(weekLine) == today)
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                string targetDirectory;
                                targetDirectory = string.Format(@"C:\MyScripts");

                                p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
                                p.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = targetDirectory;
                                p.StartInfo.FileName = "monthTest.bat";
                                p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
                                p.Start();
                                p.WaitForExit();
                                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
                            }
                            catch (Exception ex)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("Exception Occurred: {0}, {1}", ex.Message, ex.StackTrace.ToString());
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    try
                    {
                        string targetDirectory;
                        targetDirectory = string.Format(@"C:\MyScripts");

                        p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
                        p.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = targetDirectory;
                        p.StartInfo.FileName = "weekTest.bat";
                        p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
                        p.Start();
                        p.WaitForExit();
                        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Exception Occurred: {0}, {1}", ex.Message, ex.StackTrace.ToString());
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
            //System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried many varieties of the above code with mostly the same results. I can typically only get the weekly script to run.

Comment: monthTest.bat must be run when today = 1/15/2015

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the reason your code is not working properly is the

```
else 
{
    return;
}
```

If today's date is not on the first line in the month file, the application will exit.

If I understand your requirements right you shall execute:

- Script A.bat if today's date is present in file A.txt.
- Script B.bat if today's date is present in file A.txt and B.txt.

If so, I would do something like the below. You may want to change the conditions when to run what script if I misunderstood your requirements.

```
namespace Automate_Script
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DateTime today =  DateTime.Today;
            // display today's date in console window.
            Console.WriteLine("\n\t\tToday is {0}", today.ToString("d"));

            if (!FileContainsDate(@"C:\MyScripts\weekDates.txt", today))
                return; // Todays date not present in week dates, nothing shall be done.

            if (FileContainsDate(@"C:\MyScripts\monthDates.txt", today))
            {
                RunScript("monthTest.bat");
            }
            else
            {
                RunScript("weekTest.bat");
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static bool FileContainsDate(string dateFile, DateTime date)
        {
            try
            {
                string[] dates = File.ReadAllLines(dateFile);
                return dates.Any(line => Convert.ToDateTime(line) == date);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                return false; 
            }
        }

        private static void RunScript(string scriptFile)
        {
            try
            {
                Process p = new Process();
                p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
                p.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"C:\MyScripts";
                p.StartInfo.FileName = scriptFile;
                p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
                p.Start();
                p.WaitForExit();
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Exception Occurred: {0}, {1}", ex.Message, ex.StackTrace.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked perfectly! Thank you Lars N! And thank you to everyone else that offered solutions. I really appreciate your time and effort.

Answer (score 0):

First, I would describe your scenario a bit different: If the current date is in File B, then execute monthTest.bat. If not, check if it's in File A, then execute weekTest.bat. If it isn't in either one, do nothing.

You can use LINQ to query the arrays for the existence of your date:

```
var fileToRun = string.Empty;
if (dateLinesMonth.Any(x => Convert.ToDateTime(x) == today)
{
    fileToRun = "monthTest.bat";
}
else if (dateLinesWeek.Any(x => Convert.ToDateTime(x) == today)
{
    fileToRun = "weekTest.bat";
}

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(fileToRun)) 
{
    // create and run process
}
```

Answer (score 0):

OK So I seriously simplified what you had and I converted your arrays of strings to a list.  I also cut out your read from file, because I didn't want to have that in dotfiddle.  Here's another way to do it.

You can see the following code on dotfiddle. https://dotnetfiddle.net/QYjoqw

```
public static void Main()
{
    var today = "1/8/2015";

    // create the string arrays to hold the dates from the text files.     Initialize to null.
    List<string> dateLinesWeek = null;
    List<string> dateLinesMonth = null;

    // this is the text file that contains the dates for week-end run dates.
    dateLinesWeek = new List<string>() {
        "1/1/2015", 
        "1/8/2015", 
        "1/15/2015", 
        "1/22/2015", 
        "1/29/2015"
    };
    dateLinesMonth= new List<string>() 
    {
        "1/15/2015", 
        "2/15/2015", 
        "3/15/2015"
    };

    if (dateLinesMonth.Contains(today))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Execute B");
    }
    else if(dateLinesWeek.Contains(today))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Execute A");
    }
```

Comment: I appreciate your effort, but reading from the text files is a requirement for this. This solution will be implemented with multiple clients, and we don't want to hard code the dates in the actual application because each client could be different.

Comment: I was just simplifying it because I don't have your files.  Just put your reading script in place of the hard coded dates I put in there.

Answer (score 0):

You selected the `batch-file` tag in this question, so I posted a batch-file solution (that is much simpler than the C# one).

```
@echo off
setlocal

rem Get today's date and eliminate left zeros in each part
set today=%date:/0=/%

rem If there's a date in file A that's equal to today's date...
findstr /L "%today%" A.txt > NUL
if not errorlevel 1 (

   rem then look at file B to see if today's date is contained in file B.
   findstr /L "%today%" B.txt > NUL

   rem If it is in file B...
   if not errorlevel 1 (
      rem run batch file "B"
      call B.bat
   ) else (
      rem run batch file "A"
      call A.bat
   )

)

rem If today's date is not listed in file A, do nothing
```